# Rearranging an Equation

Tags: probability

How does the the rearranging of the equation below work?

I can't quite see what is happening.

$(1-(1-r)^x)N-(1-(1-r)^{x-1})N =Nr(1-r)^{x-1}.$

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? When I simplify this I obtain $Nr(1-r)^{x-1}$.

Comment: Sorry! I left out the Nr. Could you tell me how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to look at the expression
$$
\left( 1-(1-r)^{x} \right)N - \left( 1-(1-r)^{x-1} \right)N
$$
Expanding the brackets we obtain
$$
-N(1-r)^{x} + N(1-r)^{x-1}
$$
so this is equal to
$$
-N(1-r)^{x-1}(1-r) + N(1-r)^{x-1}.
$$
Now you should get the right terms together. Can you finish it from here?

Comment: I'm such an idiot. You're the best. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! You can accept an answer by clicking on the symbol next to the solution.